# IE automation VBA - How to access a span button without any text

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I am trying to do IE automation using VBA and facing a problem in clicking a span element.

I want to click on the below element.

```
<span class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small de-icon-export_item " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnIconEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnIconEl" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>
```

Below is the code for the HTML Page. Since it is an intranet page, can't post the link for the same.

```
<a tabindex="-1" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-btn-over" id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export" style="margin: 0px; left: 32px; top: 2px; right: auto;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" componentId="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export" data-qtip="Export">
  <span class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-toolbar-small " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnWrap" role="presentation" data-ref="btnWrap" unselectable="on">
    <span class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-toolbar-small  x-btn-no-text x-btn-icon x-btn-icon-left x-btn-button-center " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnEl" unselectable="on">
      <span class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small de-icon-export_item " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnIconEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnIconEl" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-toolbar-small" id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Below are the options I have tried using other reference posts.
Find the Span element by ID and then find the parent for it, which seems to be the  tag.

```
doc.getElementById("KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnIconEl").ParentNode.Click
```

Tried with class name as well.

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small de-icon-export_item").Item(0).ParentNode.Click
```

I am able to find the element in the parent frame using the debugging option, so that should rule out the iFrame, isn't it?

I am very new to HTML, JavaScript so not understanding what else to check.

Comment: First, please check your posted html resource, under the <a> element, it contains some <span> tags and a </a> tag, which missing the start tag, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PWoP.png). Whether all of the <span> element is inside the <a> tag? Second, from your code, it seems that multiple elements will have the same ID and Class value, in this scenario, it is better to use the getElementsByClassName method to find elements, then based on the index to find special element. Finally, about the iframe tag, you could use F12 developer tools to check whether the element is in the iframe tag.

Comment: Thanks @ZhiLv-MSFT for your inputs. I updated the HTML code now. Based on the latest html code, you can see that there is only 1 match for the class name and id we are looking for and I have tried both of them. I tried to find whether the data is getting loading in an iFrame using the developer tools, but that is not the case. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the provide code not inside the Iframe tag, you could use the following code to find the element.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim selectItem As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "<website url>"

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        'Find element by ID property.
       'Set selectItem = IE.document.getElementById("KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnIconEl")
       'Debug.Print SelectItem.innerText
       'selectItem.Click

       'Find element by Class Name 
       Set selectItem = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small de-icon-export_item")(0)

       Debug.Print selectItem.innerText
       selectItem.Click

    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note: please remember to change the website url to your owns.

In order to see the effect more clearly, I have added the onclick event in the span tag and a tag. The Html resource as below:

```
 <a tabindex="-1" onclick="alert('a click');" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-btn-over" id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export" style="margin: 0px; left: 32px; top: 2px; right: auto;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" componentId="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export" data-qtip="Export">
    <span class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-toolbar-small " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnWrap" role="presentation" data-ref="btnWrap" unselectable="on">
        <span class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-toolbar-small  x-btn-no-text x-btn-icon x-btn-icon-left x-btn-button-center " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnEl" unselectable="on">
            <span class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small de-icon-export_item " id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnIconEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnIconEl" onclick="alert('hi');" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-toolbar-small" id="KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

The screenshot:

[image]

If the elements inside the iframe tag, Html resource like this:

[image]

You could use the following code to find the iframe element first, and then, access the span element.

```
   Set selectItem = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("KEY_TOOLTIP_Export-btnIconEl")
   'Debug.Print selectItem.innerText 'debug, check the inner text.
   selectItem.Click
```